# ValueError: could not convert string to float -- how to convert list of numpy array to float?

Tags: python, numpy

I am using protein-ligand affinity value file as input that return its values to list. Code is

```py
def sep_input_file(input_file):
    lines = preprocessing(read_file(open(input_file,"r")))
    
    if lines.shape[1] == 2:
        return list(lines[:,0]), list(lines[:,1]), list(np.ones(len(lines)))
    elif lines.shape[1] == 3:
        return list(lines[:,0]), list(lines[:,1]), list(np.array(lines[:,2], dtype = np.float32))
```

Input file is:

| protein | ligand | affinity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ./data/complexes/2hyyProtein.mol2 | ./data/complexes/2hyyLigand.mol2 | 10.2 |

Please suggest me how to resolve it?

Getting the error

```
error:

return list(lines[:,0]), list(lines[:,1]), list(np.array(lines[:,2], dtype = np.float32))
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Comment: this is probably an error in the file. Although is strange since pymol is alredy writen in python. Maybe you can check if the floating point for the numbers in the file is a "," instead of a "." that means is written 7,52 instead of 7.52. If you are working on a french computer this might be a common error when you export the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are most likely strings that can't be parsed into floats in the `affinity` column. Try replacing

```
list(np.array(lines[:,2], dtype = np.float32))
```

with

```
result = []
for data in lines[:,2]:
    try:
        value = float(data.replace(',', '.').strip())
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        value = None
    result.append(value)
```

There will be `None` values in the result where the parsing fails.